# Trying to login to a drive connected to my Hauwei B618 Router with Python

Tags: python, authentication, networking

I am trying to write a basic backup tool to use in python 3. It all works fine except, if I have not signed in to the drive, it obviously errors out. This is the error it gives me: `OSError: [WinError 1326] The user name or password is incorrect: '//192.168.8.1/Test/'`

I am hoping that there is a way to do something like in the path have the username and password so that it inserts it when trying to access the drive. But I don't know how.

What I am using on the router side is Samba Server which is builtin to my Hauwei B618 router. I have an external drive connected via the usb port. On the router I have created an account username: Test and password: Code1234

If anyone has an easy way to login, before it tries to backup, would be great. I a real noob. So the simpler the better. . .

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

device = ConnectHandler(device_type='huawei', ip='192.168.8.1', username='Test', password='code1234')

shutil.copytree('C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Pictures/bg_drop','//192.168.8.1/Test/JMicron-00800154_usb1_1/Tristan Laptop Backups/Testing')
```

Comment: You should use a Python SMB library to log in, for example: https://pypi.org/project/smbprotocol/

Comment: Thanks @m0skit0

Do you know if this will work with SMB1 - that is what samba server uses unfortunately. Thanks.

Comment: No idea. That was just an example. You can try and if it doesn't work you can maybe search for another library that is compatible with SMB1.